# Using an XSLT variable in a 'test' string that contains a backslash

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to write an XSLT file to use with the Wix Harvest tool ([heat.exe](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)). Below is a psuedocode example of the XML generated by the tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
            <Component Id="component1" Guid="{guidstring1}">
                <File Id="file1" Source="SourceDir\target.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="component2" Guid="{guidstring2}">
                <File Id="file2" Source="SourceDir\otherfile.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
```

I would like to add a Shortcut subnode to the File with a Source attribute of `SourceDir\target.exe` while setting the KeyPath attribute of other Files to `no`. ([How to create shortcuts to files harvested by heat.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41140034/1281841) was used as a base for this attempt)

The following is a snippet from the XSLT file I have so far. The parameter `targetFile` is normally set dynamically but for the sake of example I have defined it as a static string.

```
<xsl:param name="targetFile" select="'target.exe'" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='//wixns:Component/wixns:File[@Source]'>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='not (@Source = SourceDir\target.exe)'>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">
                    <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <Shortcut
                    Id="startmenuShortcut"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                    Directory="ProgramMenuDir"
                    WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
                    Name="Target"
                    Icon="target.exe"
                    IconIndex="0"
                    Advertise="yes"
                />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This XSLT file accomplishes what I want it to when I set the `when` test string explicitly. However, I would like to make use of the "targetFile" parameter that I defined in the beginning. My first attempt was to use the following:

```
<xsl:when test='not (@Source = SourceDir\$targetFile)'>
```

This resulted in the error

```
Expected token ')', found '\'. not (@Source = SourceDir -->\<-- $targetFile)
```

Surrounding the variable with `{}` like `{$targetFile}` had similar results. Trying to surround the whole search string in quotes like so

```
<xsl:when test='not (@Source = "SourceDir\$targetFile")'>
```

did not correctly identify the File component and just applied the KeyPath attribute modification to everything.

Setting the variable as `<xsl:param name="targetFile" select="'SourceDir\target.exe'" />` and then setting the test to

```
<xsl:when test='not (@Source = $targetFile)'>
```

resulted in the correct modifications, however I would like to use the "target.exe" string elsewhere in the XSLT file so I'd like to keep the variable set to that.

At this point I suspect that I am using the wrong syntax for this operation but my attempts at finding documentation to clarify things have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `concat` function `@Source = concat("SourceDir\", $targetFile)`.